# Drupal - Changing decimal field in database causes errors

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I needed to change the data_scale of a decimal field implemented by the module "computed field".
I changed the `field_data_MYFIELD` directly in database (from 10,2 to 10,4). 
I also modified the `field_revision_MYFIELD` the same way.
As third step, I modified the data of the `field_config` by changing:

FROM

```
s:14:"data_precision";s:2:"10";s:10:"data_scale";s:1:"2";
```

TO

```
s:14:"data_precision";s:2:"10";s:10:"data_scale";s:1:"4";
```

As I'm trying to clear caches with drush cc all, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in
>   DRUPAL_SITE/modules/field/field.info.class.inc on line 495

The line 495 is:

```
// Make sure all expected field settings are present.
$field['settings'] += field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
```

I enabled the error log in index.php and have the following errors:

- unserialize(): Error at offset 330 of 1314 bytes in DRUPAL_SITE/modules/field/field.crud.inc on line 374
- Notice: Undefined index: settings in DRUPAL_SITE/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.install on line 13
- Undefined index: settings in DRUPAL_SITE/modules/field/field.info.class.inc on line 495
- Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in DRUPAL_SITE/modules/field/field.info.class.inc on line 495

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never a good idea to alter settings via mysql directly, take a look here to do it from code : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79378/changing-a-field-type-from-integer-to-decimal/151367#151367

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I know my approach was wrong ... I will try to fix it with the submited link and let you know further. Merci pour votre aide, Laurent (je poursuis en anglais pour le reste des internautes).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem lays on the unserialized data in field_config but have no idea of what is wrong. By adding the following code to the /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php: # Show 1000 rows instead of 30 by default
$cfg['MaxRows'] = 1000;
# Show BLOB data as a string not hex.
$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = false;
# Show BLOB data in row detail pages.
$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = false;
# Show BLOB data on table browse pages.  Hack to hardcode all requests.
$_REQUEST['display_blob'] = true;

Comment: With tools like mysql workbench you can display blob by default (and it is way faster than phpmyadmin...). Did you try to serialize/unserialize with php code?

Comment: Hi Laurent, you were right. After some tests, the problem is now resolved.  It appears that editing the Blob data (for computed fields with php code inside) directly from phpmyadmin is not a good idea as far as it adds many additional char that doesn't match the lenght of the S. I fixed it by changing different values of the S lenght in order to match the content of each S.  I wil try your suggestion of using mysql workbrench for the future. I did'nt try to serialize/unserialize with php code because the problem was solved before, but I will.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Good to hear, you can also use sql developper, toad, .. anything will be better than phpmyadmin (only use it when you can not install a real database ide on your computer, mysql workbench is on portableapps.com btw). Bon courage pour la suite de ton projet.

Comment: Je suivrai vos conseils avec plaisir. Pour l'instant je teste MySQL Workbrench avec succès. Merci encore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could have use an hook_update to alter the field.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Clive. I did'nt paste the whole data ...apologize. The data_precision etc keys are indeed inside a database key within that string. I tested the data content into http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/ (as suggested) and the string is not valid ... you were right. I fixed it by changing different values of the S lenght in order to match the content of each S . After some tests, the problem is now resolved. It appears that editing the Blob data (for computed fields with php code inside) directly from phpmyadmin is not a good idea as far as it adds many additional char that doesn't match the lenght of the S. Thanks again for your help.